# Explode Comma Separated Values with or without Spaces

Tags: php

An input field on a form accepts a list of comma separated values.

How can I turn those values into an array whether the user enters values with a space after each comma: `one, two, three` or without `one,two,three`?

Basically I want to combine
`$myArray = explode(', ', $myString);`
and
`$myArray = explode(',', $myString);`

Comment: You have to use `explode` not `implode`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to try the below code:

```
$myString = "one, two, three";
$myArray = explode(',', $myString);
$trimmed_myArray = array_map('trim',$myArray);
print_r($trimmed_myArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, you want trimmed values after exploding. You can use `explode` & `trim` & `array_map`.

```
$input= 'one, two, three';
$v = explode(',', $input);

$v = array_map('trim', $v);
var_dump($v);
```

**Output**

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "one"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "two"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "three"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When the value delimiter in your string is variable, `preg_split()` offers a simple, direct process.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/3frvr))

```
$mystring='one,two,three,four, five, six, seven';
var_export(preg_split('/, ?/',$mystring));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'one',
  1 => 'two',
  2 => 'three',
  3 => 'four',
  4 => 'five',
  5 => 'six',
  6 => 'seven',
)
```

This is a clean solution because it doesn't require any string preparation or post-split iterative "mopping up".  One function call does it all.

The pattern merely explodes on a comma followed by an optional space (the `?` means zero or one occurrence of the preceding space).

Comment: perhaps `/,\s*?/` is a better regex because the provided string may or may not have a space after the commas.

Comment: If _your_ situation might also have tabs or newline characters (`\t, `\r`, `\n`), then yes, use `\s`.  If _your_ situation might have zero or more whitespace characters (instead of zero or one), then use the `*` quantifier.  Modifying the `?` quantifier in this case has no benefit at all.